# Can the minimum value of a binary search tree not be the leftmost entry?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-tree

If I construct a binary search tree as I have below, is it right? Or is such a tree not a valid binary search tree?

```
    7
   / \
  5   8
     / \
    4  10
```

Because I have followed the rule of smaller element on the left and larger element on the right. So I imagine this is a binary search tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to walk the tree manually; pretending that you're a function looking for the 4.

- You start at the root of the tree: the 7.
- 4 is less than 7, so you go left to 5.
- 4 is less than 5 so you go left again.
- There's nothing there, so you'd come to the conclusion that 4 is not in the tree.

Of course that's incorrect though, so no, this is not a valid setup  for a BST. It isn't simply that each value needs to only be in the correct position relative to its direct parent. Each value also needs to be in a correct position relative to the other nodes in the tree.

The exact position depends on the insertion order of each value, but with this configuration of values, the 4 should be to the left of the 5.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a binary tree, as each node only has two leaves.

But like others said, it's not a binary search tree. A way of judging is for each node, all left leaves' values should be smaller than self's value and all right leaves' values should be greater than self's value. Only in this way can perform binary search.